# The Responses tab is not working

Tags: support, user-interface

Since the last big user-interface overhaul of all Stack Overflow sites a few months ago,
the Responses tab stopped working.

The Responses tab can be reached directly through the URL of
`https://superuser.com/users/USERID/USERNAME?tab=responses`.

Currently, for me it shows "0 Answers" and no responses.

The same problem has arrived on SO at the same time as here, but there it
was fixed within a few days. It was never fixed on SU.

The Responses tab was very useful for me.
As a work-around, I'm using the Inbox icon, which is a bit awkward.

I'm a bit surprised that nobody noticed it before, or is it happening only for me?

Comment: Works for me. Do you have an extension or Greasemonkey script breaking it? Cleared browser cache? Try a fresh browser profile or another browser or computer.

Comment: @Mokubai: Happens to me on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Pale Moon. Have I broken the SO software with my excessive number of responses?

Comment: Doubtful. I can see your responses page and there are some 24 thousand listed there. My only guess would be some extension or blocker or perhaps your network setup is blocking one of the content servers. Try setting your DNS to 8.8.8.8 or try a VPN? Or if you are using a VPN then disable it.

Comment: @Mokubai: I don't have a single extension that can be installed on all 4 browsers. I went on a VPN, so not using my ISP's DNS, and this still happens. Why would my DNS victimize one single tab, and why did this arrive at the same time as the UI overhaul? Coincidence?

Comment: Unless there is a problem with your profile itself that doesn't present to others I don't know. It could be the kind of thing that got broken in the backend. All I know is that some ISPs have "odd" DNS filters and I've had problems with sites doing cross domain stuff as a result and occasionally taking them out of the loop can be a good diagnostic step. As I say, I can see responses on my own profile, and I can see that you are getting responses when I view your profile. Sadly checking via incognito isn't an option as that page gets hidden. I'd be tempted to use the contact form.

Comment: @Mokubai: I  just noticed that the Responses tab works for me on Meta, same as in SO. I would like to debug this on SU, but the moderators might not like me to create a dummy profile, post and comments?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: @DavidPostill: There is only a "No contents" warning on the request `https://superuser.com/users/ivc/8672/8d0c?_=1662302328790`.

Comment: Its working for me on SU too. - @harrymc, Meta.stackexchange has a sandbox that would work for this. ... or how does it look on SU meta?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: My Responses look correct on Meta and SO, so would probably be OK on another site. The question is if the SU moderators would ignore my using a fake account and post, clearly marked so, for one day while I compare requests in the hope of finding some discrepancy. If not allowed, then I would try the contact form, but I would not have any real information to communicate.

Comment: As long as you don't answer your own questions or vote for yourself, its fine. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685 is probably the definitive list, and I have an alternate account I use for various reasons myself

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Thanks - I would do so, deleting post and account once I'm done. If I find anything interesting, I might post it here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that this problem is only happening to me.

I may debug it in the future when I have time, but for the moment there
is nothing more to be done.

EDIT : I was too lazy to debug the problem, but since yesterday
the Responses tab started working again for me for the first time
since several years. Bravo, Stack Overflow!